# How can I expose qemu-guest-agent QMP capabilities to the qmp tcp server in qemu?

Tags: sockets, tcp, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm using qemu-system-x86_64 to run a vm exposing QMP commands via TCP connection in this way:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-smp 4 -m 4096 \
-vga std \
-display vnc=:0 \
-netdev user,id=n0 \
-device e1000,netdev=n0 \
-usb -device usb-tablet \
-qmp tcp:localhost:8124,server,nowait \
-k en-us \
-boot d \
-hda /filesystem/filesystem.img
```

Everything is ok, because I can send QMP commands to qemu locally via TCP socket connection on port 8124.

Then I installed qemu-guest-agent on the vm (Ubuntu 21.04 desktop) and I created the virtio ports required by the quemu-guest-agent service in this way:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-smp 4 -m 4096 \
-vga std \
-display vnc=:0 \
-netdev user,id=n0 \
-device e1000,netdev=n0 \
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/qga.sock,server,nowait,id=qga0 \
-device virtio-serial \
-device virtserialport,chardev=qga0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 \
-usb -device usb-tablet \
-qmp tcp:localhost:8124,server,nowait \
-k en-us \
-boot d \
-hda /filesystem/filesystem.img
```

quemu-guest-agent systemd service is up and running as expected (obviously on a local socket, not via TCP).

Now I want to see **qemu-guest-agent QMP capabilities via TCP socket connection**.
How can I achieve this?

Based on the [official guide](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/GuestAgent) I have to change chardev in this way `-chardev qga_proxy,id=qga0 \` but it's not working. It seems an obsolete info in that guide, because this command is not supported today. It throws error: *qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev qga_proxy,id=qga0: 'qga_proxy' is not a valid char driver name*

Which is the correct way to expose guest-agent QMP commands through TCP socket?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to associate the virtio serial device with a TCP chardev.

Iow, replace:
`-chardev socket,path=/tmp/qga.sock,server,nowait,id=qga0` (unix socket) with
`-chardev socket,id=qga0,host=localhost,port=9876,server=on` (tcp socket).

Fwiw, `qga_proxy` never happened, it was just some sketchy ideas on the wiki.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried this solution with two sockets, but in this way I have 2 tcp ports, one for qemu and another one for qemu guest agent, right? Or with a single connection to 8124, can I send and receive both qmp and guest commands?